# jsp, search of database

Tags: jsp, search

I have problem with this code. It's about to search database, and view results. My problem is that code is "working" till time when i try to search something what does not exist. Then even if i search for something what exist in database ( music album for example coldplay ), it shows nothing in result... Everything works till that time. Can you please take a look for this code and see if anything can be done to make it work better ?
Thank you for your time !

```
<%!
ResultSet rs;
String var="no query";
int test=-1;
String msg="";
String change1(String temp){
    String value="";
     for(int i=0; i<temp.length();i++)
     {
       if(temp.charAt(i)=='/')
          value=value + ')';
       else if(temp.charAt(i)=='.') 
          value=value+"%";
       else if(temp.charAt(i)=='m') 
        {
          int j=i;
          j++;
          if(temp.charAt(j)=='p')
          {
            j++;
            if(temp.charAt(j)=='3')
            {
              i=j;
              value=value+"|";               
            }                            
          }
          if(j==i+1 || j==i+2)
          {
            char c = temp.charAt(i);
            int k = (int) c;
            c=(char)++k;
            value=value+c;
          }

        }
       else
         {
           char c = temp.charAt(i);
           int j = (int) c;
           c=(char)++j;
           value=value+c;
         }                                                                    
     }
     return value;     
}
String changeToValid(String temp)
  {
     String value="";
     for(int i=0; i<temp.length();i++)
     {
       if(temp.charAt(i)=='.')
          value=value + "&";
       else
          value=value+temp.charAt(i);                                                           
     }
     return value;
  }
  String validate(String temp)
  {
     String value="";
     for(int i=0; i<temp.length();i++)
     {
       if(temp.charAt(i)==' ')
         {
           int j=i;
           if(temp.charAt(++j)==' ')
               break;
           else
            value=value+' ';   
         }
       else
          value=value+temp.charAt(i);                                                           
     }
     return value;
  }

%>
<%
 if(request.getParameter("query")!=null)
   {
     var=validate(request.getParameter("query").toLowerCase());       
   }
 try{
                  rs=DataConnection.getReordData("SELECT * FROM music_info WHERE MATCH(title,album,artist,body) AGAINST('"+var+"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"); 
                  if(!rs.next())
                  {
                      test=0;
                      msg="No result Found";
                  }

    }catch(Exception e){out.println(e);}

%>
```

Comment: `change1()` and `changeToValid()` are defined but not used anywhere in your code. Are they relevant to your example?

Comment: Hey, changeToValid definition appear in every file like : home.jsp, lshow.jsp, show.jsp, search.jsp also - so each file which is used for other 'link-pages' of website when you click on button : Menu, Albums, Search album etc... it works fine, i tested it, results appear. (its used later in code)
and about change1 , its for hidden "path" for mp3 file on server (hidden because user dont need to know path, but i use that for player)

Comment: Jesus christ, you're using so many bad practices here, try looking at servlets, use that, also, please clean up your for loop monstrosity, that's going to be horrible to maintain